# When I update a Subject<boolean> in NgOnInit it does not change other component associeted to be visible using ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, subject-observer

I hope you doing well.

I have a loading component this component when is visible stays above all content with an loading circle and block all below elements to be touched during the loading process.

To activate the loading component I need to change a`Subject<boolean>` var to true to make this component visible and false to hidden;
[image]
[image]

Sometimes I need to make the loading visible durring the initialization of a component so I change this Subject inside the NgOnInit method unfurtunally it does not make the component visible, I don't know why it is not working.

To change the value in another components I use service, a service hold Subject variable and has methods to change it.
[image]

I found a "solution", change the Subject value inside a setTimeout(()=>{here});
[image]
[image]

I don't think this is the best way to do it right so please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `OnPush` change detection strategy.

Change it to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` or remove it completely to fallback to the default one, and app will start behaving as you expect.

If you want to stick to `OnPush` strategy, you have to read some resources available online to know the implications of such approach.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any difference. Still not show loading. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the subject emits a new value, the async pipe marks your component to be checked in the next change detection cycle. The problem here is, that there is no change detection cycle happening in between the `startLoading` and `stopLoading` call of `findAll`, so the `startLoading` will not have any visible effect. Only the finished http call will trigger a change detection, but that is too late.

To fix it, you need to trigger change detection manually after calling `startLoading` by using the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any difference. Still not show loading. I tried with changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, in loading component but any difference. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your subject

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.status.next(true)
}
```

inside ngAfterViewInit lifehHookCycle.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any difference. Still not show loading. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please add your code to any online platform then I can help you?
As I see in your code snippet everything you wrote is correct.